# How to integrate red5 default application publisher with the php web page which is on WAMP server?

Tags: php, red5

I need to broadcast live video from webcam to my PHP app web page.
I have installed and run red5 default application "publisher" successfully.Now,I need to integrate my PHP web page with red5 publisher application.

On red5 publisher page, that is: 
      `localhost:5080/demos/publisher.html`

I need to change the location of server that is `"rtmp://localhost/oflaDemoset"` to my PHP web page which is in WAMP server. let's say `"http://www.myapp.com/home" 
but whenever i changed this it shows blank page.`.

Just want to know how to change location in  red5 Default publisher APP.

Noone knows...hows strange..!

Answer (score 0):

yes nobody knows as the question is rather irritating. You can't simply exchange the rtmp URL with your PHP. You need to install the Red5 server at  the machine that runs your website. Or some other "online" server. Simply changing the URL from localhost to your PHP host will not work.

Sebastian

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response...! Can you please explain me more that how should i install Red5 server that runs my website.

Comment: I think you should first study some basics. Red5 can't run your website. It is an Apache Tomcat Java Servlet Container. You cannot run PHP websites with it. You need to create some kind of Java Servlet inside in it. And you need to create your own custom Red5 application.

Comment: Thanks ! Can you show me some links pointing to create custom Red5 Application !

Comment: See those demo sample applications: https://code.google.com/p/red5/source/browse/#svn%2Fjava%2Fexample%2Ftrunk

Answer (score 0):

Clients need to connect to RTMP server to watch the video.
So RTMP server must be on a public IP or website. 
Localhost points to own computer so users will not be connecting to server if you leave that setting.